# Computing a generating set of the kernel of a module

Tags: algorithms, gr.group-theory, modules, linear-algebra

Crossposted from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62125/computing-a-generating-set-of-the-kernel-of-a-module), since I'm not getting any answer and I think the question is suitable here.

Given a generating set of a $\mathbb{Z_k}$-module $M \subseteq {\mathbb{Z}_k}^n$, is there an (efficient) known algorithm to compute a generating set of {$u \in {\mathbb{Z}_k}^n  :  \forall v \in M \quad v \cdot u = 0$}? It is quite simple when $k = p^i$ for a prime $p$ (since it becomes a vector space), but I have no clue what to do when $k$ is composite.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{Z}_k$ a field for $k=p^i$ when $i>1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The magic words are "Smith Normal Form". The magic reference is "Integral Matrices" by M. Newman, which discusses many questions of this sort in a lucid way.